# Translation of "Do it for her"

Tags: idiom, english-to-latin-translation

Could someone help me translate "***Do it for her***" into Latin?

Context:
The "it" refers to keep working, fighting, striving, while "her" actually refers to two persons; sometimes individually (so I'd like it in singular personal pronoun).

Background:
I'm bipolar, and I try to surround myself with motivational phrases for when I have my lows.
For a long time, I've had "Do it for her!" (inspired by this scene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3njZSDjW7Q4) taped above my monitor, and it's by far the most effective one. It's in reference to the daughter I lost and my GF who suffers from both mental and physical issues.
I'd like to upgrade it to a tattoo, but at the same time keep it somewhat private (as in not blatantly clear to someone who sees it) - hence the Latin.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of ways of translating any given phrase into Latin, so you may get a variety of suggestions. I'd go with:

> Pro ea facito

*Facito* is a so-called "future imperative", which is a form that can be used for commands about the future or ones that are temporally non-specific. I chose it partly because the context you describe seems to suit an imperative that's not about a single specific occasion, but also because the regular (present) imperative of the verb "do" is *fac*, which happens to sound like a common English expletive so may not be something you want permanently inscribed on your body (though who knows).

"For her" can be expressed in a number of ways, but not all of them are gender-specific: e.g. *huic* can mean "for her" or "for him". *Pro ea* is specifically feminine.

I've left out "it", which is common in Latin -- pronouns that aren't emphasized or whose referents are clear from context are usually omitted.

In terms of word order, placing the "for her" part first gives it some extra emphasis, of the kind that you'd express in English by intonational stress: "do it for HER" rather than "DO IT for her".

Comment: Thank you so much for showing your reasoning, TKR. It makes it easier to grasp the difference. If I understand you correctly (grammar's never been my strong suit, and I'm an ESL), a quick and dirty translation would be something akin to "For her, do!", and that "Pro ea fac" would be more like "Do things for her now!" while "Pro ea facito" is more in the line of "Continously do things for her". Tough choice then; while it is intended to keep me going, it's in the here and now I need the push the most to not give up - so both of them fit very well in their own right (the almost-expletive...

Comment: [continued:] ... doesn't bother me). I'll have to give it some thought. I'm very grateful for the help. I've been wanting to do this for a very long time, but limited to free online translation programs, these are the "best" I found: Pugna pro ea.
Facet sunt propter illam.
Agite id propter illam. And I'm sure to someone who actually knows Latin, that's like the "My hovercraft is full of eels" scetch in Monty Python (and I have a feeling the first one would mean to actually brawl). So again, my deepest thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*Fac id huic*, I'd say where "id" is general.

Comment: *Facere* has an irregular imperative, *fac*.